# User input manipulation

Tags: python-3.9

Please I'm in need of a lift right now. I want the user to be able to have the option of re-entering his numerical input if perhaps, he/she entered an alphabet by mistake.
Right now it just loops infinitely on the "Please select a valid option" and "Try again" outputs.

```
print("\n-----Factorial Calculator------\n")


def option():
    opt = (input('Try again? y/n: '))
    if option == 'y':
        facto(num)
    elif option == 'n':
        exit()
    else:
        print("Please select a valid option")
        option()


def facto(factorial):
    fact = 1

    for nums in range(1, num+1):
        fact = fact * nums
    return fact


try:
    num = int(input("Number(Just input the number): "))

except ValueError:
    print("Invalid input")
    option()


print(f" {num}! = {facto(num)}")
```

Comment: you can use a while loop. enter your choice 'y/n' as the condition.

Answer (score 0):

First, rather than calling `option` recursively, simply put a loop inside it.

Second, when the user enters `y` into the `"Try again?"` input, it should not calculate the factorial there, but return the user back to the original input, by breaking out of the loop within the `option` call.

Putting these two together will fix `option`:

```
def option():
    while True:
        retry = input('Try again? y/n: ')
        if retry == 'y':
            break
        elif retry == 'n':
            exit()
        else:
            print("Please select a valid option")
```

Third, you need some kind of loop around your initial input, otherwise how will they enter the number again after indicating they want to try again?

Fix this by sticking the initial `num` assignment and `option` call in a `while` loop, with the same `try; except` statement you had before:

```
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input("Number(Just input the number): "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        option()
        continue
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond!
However, it works until you input "n". It just takes you  back to num = int(input("Number(Just input the number):"))

Comment: @Gilbert that sounds like it has to do with how you’re running the program, if I run it from cmd it works as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I see someone else got an answer in ahead of me which identified the bug in `option()` and the bug which prevents user re-entering the number but I'll post this anyway because there are other ways your code can be restructured.

```
print("\n-----Factorial Calculator------\n")

# Each function should handle just one thing
# Eg, option() should just handle whether user wants to continue, not try to handle factorial calc
# Also it's best to let the mainline logic decide whether to exit() or not
# This function should just return 'y' or 'n' 

# Note that the original code captured the user's option in variable `opt` but then checked variable `option`.
# That's why it looped endlessly

def option():
    opt = ' '
    while ( opt != 'y' and opt != 'n' ):
        opt = (input('Try again? y/n: '))
        if opt == 'y':
            return opt
        elif opt == 'n':
            return opt
        else:
            print("Please select a valid option")

# You specified argument `factorial` in original code but then did not use it.
# It still worked because the variable `num` was defined at the top level in the mainline
# Functions should be self-contained and rely only on the arguments that are passed into them

def facto(n):
    fact = 1

    for nums in range(1, n+1):
        fact = fact * nums
    return fact

opt = 'y'
is_print = False
while ( opt == 'y' ):
    try:
        num = int(input("Number(Just input the number): "))
        opt = 'n'
        is_print = True

    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input")
        opt = option()


if ( is_print ):
     print(f" {num}! = {facto(num)}")
```

Comment: Thank you  for taking your time to respond!
However, the code worked until the user inputs 'n'.
It throws an error message of num being undefined.....or so.

Comment: @Gilbert Ahh, my bad, I  added an if-statement at the end so it only prints if the user actually entered a valid number for calculation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help, but after struggling with it for a couple of days and taking few days off due to illness, I somehow did it. Eureka!

```
def facto(n):
    fact = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        fact = fact * i
    return fact


def opt():
    option = (input("Do you want to try again?  y/n:  "))
    if option == 'y':
        number()

    elif option == 'n':
        exit()

    else:
        print("\nPlease select a valid option.")
        opt()


def number():
    try:
        num = int(input("Number: "))
        print(f"{num}! = {facto(num)}")
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input! Please input integers only")
        opt()


number()
```